# find model class of array in hash rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I am trying to figure out WHICH model  is left in an array so that I can make conditional statements using that model.

```
set_hash = {
  some_array_one: RedModel.some_scope,
  some_array_two: BlueModel.some_scope,
  some_array_three: GreenModel.some_scope
}
```

Assuming this hash has

```
some_array_one.count = 0,
some_array_two.count = 5,
some_array_three.count = 0,
```

**Then the answer to set_class should equal:  BlueModel**

This is how I've tried to find that answer

```
 set_class =  set_hash.reject{|k, v| v.count.zero?}.map{|k, v| v.first.class.name}
```

However, what I get is:

```
 ["BlueModel"]
```

How do I constantize that string-in-array (probably not the correct term.)
When I try to use constantize, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `constantize' for ["Item"]:Array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I constantize that string-in-array (probably not the correct
>   term.)

There is actually a method called `constantize` that does exactly what it sounds like it does:

```
"BlueModel".constantize
#=> BlueModel
```

Actually, it is string only because you are calling `v.first.class.name`, remove the `name` call and you'll get a model itself.

```
set_class =  set_hash.reject{ |k, v| v.count.zero?}.map{ |k, v| v.first.class.name }.map(&:constatize).first
set_class =  set_hash.reject{ |k, v| v.count.zero?}.map{ |k, v| v.first.class }.first
```

Comment: Yes,  but it gives me this NoMethodError: undefined method `constantize' for ["Item"]:Array

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere either add `set_class.map(&:constantize).first` or `set_class.first.constantize`

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere I added few options, I would definitely go with the latest one

Comment: Somehow that doesn't let me call kind_of? on it.  Why is that?

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere I do not understand what does not let you call `kind_of?`?

Comment: I'd like to be able to do set_class.kind_of(BlueModel) and get the value "true",  but I am not getting that.  It looks like I should.

Comment: Nevermind.  set_class.new.kind_of?(BlueModel) works.

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere `set_class == BlueModel` => `true`, but `set_class` is_a `Class`. So you should use `set_class == BlueModel`